# Check checkbox with column from table

Tags: checkbox, mysqli, checked

Can anyone show me, what i'm doing wrong?
I using c_id from company to give checkbox a value for later use.
I using name from company to write the name of the company next to the checkbox.
I using c_id from artistscompany to print "checked" in the checkboxes, where c_id from artistscompany are equal to c_id from artists.

```
$slsql = 'SELECT * FROM artistscompany WHERE a_id='.$ad_id; 
$blsql = 'SELECT c_id, name FROM company WHERE c_id > 1'; 
if (($bl_result = mysqli_query($dbh, $blsql))AND($sl_result = mysqli_query($dbh, $slsql))) { 
while($bl_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($bl_result)){
$sl_raekke = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sl_result);
foreach((array)$sl_raekke as $sl_row){}
echo '<input type="checkbox" name="belongs[]" value="'.$bl_row['c_id'].'"'; if($sl_row == $bl_row['c_id']){echo'checked';}ELSE{echo'';} echo'>&nbsp;'.$bl_row['name'].'<br />';
}
mysqli_free_result($bl_result); 
mysqli_free_result($sl_result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM artistscompany a, company c WHERE c.c_id > 1 AND 
          c.c_id=a.c_id AND a_id='.$ad_id;
```

Now use this query to fetch and display from db.

*a and c are used to refer to the fields*. You want the **c_id > 1** from company table, **a_id=$variable** and **the same company ID in both tables**. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: what is the problem you are facing exactly?

Comment: Again:
I using c_id from artistscompany(table) to print "checked" in the checkboxes, where c_id from artistscompany(table) are equal to c_id from artists(table).

Comment: combine both tables in one query where the id's are equal